# using .fadeToggle() to fade in text and fade out on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very close to getting what I want but need a little more help with this.

```js
$('.change').hover(function() {
  $(this).fadeToggle('slow', 'linear', function() {
    $(this).text('wanna be CodeNinja').css('color', 'grey');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>a <span class="change">CodeNinja</span>.</h1>
```

I just want to someone to hover over the underlined CodeNinja and then for it to fade in and display Wanna Be CodeNinja and then on mouseout display CodeNinja again.

oh the domain is www.mrpben.net

Comment: What happens now, create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by providing a function to `text()` which sets the new text value based on the current, using `fadeToggle()` again once you've set the text (to display the element again) and also `toggleClass()` to set/unset the text colour. Try this:

```js
$('.change').hover(function() {
  $(this).fadeToggle('slow', function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, t) {
      return t == 'CodeNinja' ? 'wanna be CodeNinja' : 'CodeNinja';
    }).fadeToggle().toggleClass('over');
  });
});
```

```css
.change.over {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>a <span class="change">CodeNinja</span>.</h1>
```

Comment: Sure, I'm using [this signature of `text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which allows you to provide a function. The `i` param is the index of the current element and `t` is its current text value. From there I use a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to then return the required value. In this case it just toggles between the two values.

Comment: thanks dude much appreciated this is really cool. Also nice to see that I was super close too. Thanks again

Comment: The ternary is the same as this: `if (t == 'CodeNinja') { return 'wanna be CodeNinja' } else { return 'CodeNinja' }`

Comment: I was just reading up on it. :) accepted the answer, thanks again